# Проблема поведения input type file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Вопрос следующий : имеется форма с **input type="file"** отправка происходит при нажатии кнопки, все работает, пользователь может добавить только один фаил, но во время теста выяснилось, что после добавления файла например пользователь передумал и решил добавить другой, но в конечном итоге после нажатия инпута в окне нажимает отмену(тем самым пользователь хочет сохранить первый фаил) инпут чиститься, с чем связанно такое поведение инпута? и возможно ли его обойти?

Comment: это нормальное поведение кнопок, из соображений безопасности, в случае "перехода"(как обычного так и submit) или "сброса" (type=reset) поля с файлами чистятся. Не делайте переход или сброс - и поле чистится не будет.

Comment: @nick-n-a , спасибо за ответ, но немного не понятно как убрать сброс текущего файла при нажатии отмены в модалке.

Comment: Кнопку сброс вы не показали. Я предполагаю что это 1.reset - такой кнопкой пользоваться нельзя, потому что она сбрасывает всё - правильно? 2. Вариант сброса "вручную" Если у вас обычная button - поставьте type=button. 3. В обоработчике click проверьте что б функция возвращала false что б отменить submit. submit вызовет очистку.